I get an keras.Layer error when ever i use my code

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import PIL
import streamlit as st
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import tf_keras



model_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/on_device_vision/classifier/landmarks_classifier_africa_V1/1'
# model_url = 'on_device_vision_classifier_landmarks_classifier_asia_V1_1'

# label_url = 'https://www.gstatic.com/aihub/tfhub/labelmaps/landmarks_classifier_asia_V1_label_map.csv'
labels = 'https://www.gstatic.com/aihub/tfhub/labelmaps/landmarks_classifier_africa_V1_label_map.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(labels)
labels = dict(zip(df.id, df.name))

def image_processing(image):
    img_shape = (321, 321)
    cclassifier = tf.keras.Sequential([
      hub.KerasLayer(model_url, input_shape=img_shape + (3,), output_key="predictions:logits")])
    img = PIL.Image.open(image)
    img = img.resize(img_shape)
    img1 = img
    img = np.array(img) / 255.0
    img = img[np.newaxis]
    result = classifier.predict(img)
    return labels[np.argmax(result)],img1

this is a code snippet from mine
and here is the error
ValueError: Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be added to a Sequential model. Received: <tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x778d1ef394e0> (of type <class 'tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer'>)

File "/home/runner/LMDetection/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 589, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/home/runner/LMDetection/main.py", line 63, in <module>
    run()
File "/home/runner/LMDetection/main.py", line 48, in run
    prediction,image = image_processing(save_image_path)
File "/home/runner/LMDetection/main.py", line 23, in image_processing
    cclassifier = tf.keras.Sequential([
File "/home/runner/LMDetection/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.add(layer, rebuild=False)
File "/home/runner/LMDetection/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py", line 95, in add
    raise ValueError(

I tried like importing tf_keras like i saw in a similar problem and i was expecting proper output without any error but this is what happened

Hi@ shiras ahamed , It appears that you're trying to use TensorFlow Hub's KerasLayer with a Keras Sequential model but are facing difficulties. The error message suggests that KerasLayer from TensorFlow Hub cannot be added to the Sequential model using the add method. This issue occurs because KerasLayer is not a standard Keras layer and does not directly work with the Sequential model's add method.

Instead of using the Sequential model, you should use the Functional API to integrate the TensorFlow Hub layer into your model.
